# How to crawl a post dependent website using scrapy

Tags: http, post, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl an insurance website www.ehealthinsurance.com.
Its home page has a POST dependent form in which it takes certain values and
next page is generated. I am trying to pass the values but unable to see the
HTML source of the desired tag i wanted. Any suggestion will be of great help.

Inline is the scrapy code:

```
class ehealthSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "ehealth"
    allowed_domains = ["ehealthinsurance.com/"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.ehealthinsurance.com/individual-health-insurance"]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                        formname='main',
                                        formdata={'census.zipCode': '48341',
                                                  'census.requestEffectiveDate': '06/01/2013',
                                                  'census.primary.gender': 'MALE',
                                                  'census.primary.month': '12',
                                                  'census.primary.day': '01',
                                                  'census.primary.year': '1971',
                                                  'census.primary.tobacco': 'No',
                                                  'census.primary.student': 'No'}, callback=self.parseAnnonces)

    def parseAnnonces(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        data = hxs.select('//div[@class="main-wrap"]').extract()
        #print encoding
        print data
```

This is crawler in terminal response

```
  2013-04-30 16:34:16+0530 [elyse] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.ehealthin
  urance.com/individual-health-insurance> (referer: None)
  2013-04-30 16:34:17+0530 [elyse] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.ehealt
  insurance.com': <POST http://www.ehealthinsurance.com/individual-health-insuran
  e;jsessionid=F5A1123CE731FDDDC1A7A31CD46CC132.prfo23a>
  2013-04-30 16:34:17+0530 [elyse] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
  2013-04-30 16:34:17+0530 [elyse] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 257,
     'downloader/request_count': 1,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 32561,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 30, 11, 4, 17, 22000),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 8,
     'log_count/INFO': 4,
     'request_depth_max': 1,
     'response_received_count': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 30, 11, 4, 10, 494000)}
```

Can you please help me to get the desired data?

Comment: The problem is you are trying to crawl the page before it's shown: there is a page in the middle loaded - after submitting the form and before results are shown, plus redirects. Looks difficult to scrape.

Comment: Thanks alecxe. I researched about the same and workaround I understood is Selenium with scrapy. But dont how how to parse the selenium loaded page to scrapy ? Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Small trick with intermediate request and it works.
Have also corrected formname. Great debug tool of Scrapy is `inspect_response(response)`

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from healthinsspider.items import HealthinsspiderItem
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.http import Request
import time

class EhealthspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'ehealthSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['ehealthinsurance.com']
    start_urls = ["http://www.ehealthinsurance.com/individual-health-insurance"]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                        formname='form-census',
                                        formdata={'census.zipCode': '48341',
                                                  'census.requestEffectiveDate': '06/01/2013',
                                                  'census.primary.gender': 'MALE',
                                                  'census.primary.month': '12',
                                                  'census.primary.day': '01',
                                                  'census.primary.year': '1971',
                                                  'census.primary.tobacco': 'No',
                                                  'census.primary.student': 'No'}, callback=self.InterRequest,
                                                  dont_filter=True)

    def InterRequest(self, response):
        # sleep so, that our request can be processed by the server, than go to results
        time.sleep(10)
        return Request(url='https://www.ehealthinsurance.com/ehi/ifp/individual-family-health-insurance!goToScreen?referer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ehealthinsurance.com%2Fehi%2Fifp%2Findividual-health-insurance%3FredirectFormHTTP&sourcePage=&edit=false&ajax=false&screenName=best-sellers', dont_filter=True, callback=self.parseAnnonces)

    def parseAnnonces(self, response):
        inspect_response(response)
        hxs = Selector(response)
        data = hxs.select('//div[@class="main-wrap"]').extract()
        #print encoding
        print data
```

P.S. Cookies should be enabled in settings.py: `COOKIES_ENABLED=True`