# Scrapy unable to retrieve data after POST request

Tags: python, scrapy

I tried to use scrapy to crawl a few pages to make my house-hunt research less tedious. I seem to be having issues with forms that require post requests (I had no success with assessor's database website or rentometer, the spider for which is shown below).

```
class RentSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'rentometer'

    def start_requests(self):
        request = FormRequest('http://www.rentometer.com',
            formdata={'address': '179 Commonwealth Ave, Apt 1, Boston, MA', 'beds': '1'},
            callback=self.after_response)
        return [request]

    def after_response(self, response):
        with open('response_html', 'w')as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

I get no errors, yet the response html seems to go back to the main page, as if no data was entered. I do see the spider going to `http://www.rentometer.com/results`, which is the submit page for the form, but from there I get redirected back to the main page.

I tried to look through the cookies to see if there is something I'm missing, but the only thing of interest I found there was session ID, which I should get automatically. I also stumbled upon this question: [How to crawl a post dependent website using scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299054/how-to-crawl-a-post-dependent-website-using-scrapy), which doesn't have a solution, but I'm wondering if I'm facing the same issue as that poster, and if there is any workaround or ability to bypass this using another library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an easy site to scrape.

I used firebug to try it out, this is the request I see in 'net' tab:

request:

```
https://www.rentometer.com/results?
```

parameters:

```
address=179%20Commonwealth%20Ave%2C%20Apt%201%2C%20Boston%2C%20MA&
authenticity_token=%2BhrOEjFfwpI6f08lgiXB5%2B%2F9bWy0y20nVnQWn%2BKGgb0%3D&
beds=1&
latitude=42.351567&
longitude=-71.07978300000002&
price=&utf8=%E2%9C%94
```

I took another look at the form on the page and realized that authenticity_token is taken from another place on the page and tried:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

class RentSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'rentometer'
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.rentometer.com'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        request = FormRequest.from_response(response=response,
            formxpath='//form',
            formdata={'address': '179 Commonwealth Ave, Apt 1, Boston, MA', 
                      'beds': '1',},
            callback=self.after_response)
        return [request]

    def after_response(self, response):
        with open('response_html', 'w')as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

this didn't work as well, so I guessed it's because latitude and longitude are missing.

searching for them in the javacript pages in firebug I found the following code part:

```
$("#search_form").submit(function(t){var i,n;return e?void 0:
 (t.preventDefault(),i=$("#address_field").val(),n=new google.maps.Geocoder,
 n.geocode({address:i},function(t,i){var n;
 return i===google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK?(n
 =t[0].geometry.location,$("#latitude").val(n.lat()),$("#longitude").val(n.lng())
```

I added my latitude and longitude values manually:

```
formdata={'address': '179 Commonwealth Ave, Apt 1, Boston, MA', 
          'beds': '1',
          'latitude': '42.351567',
          'longitude': '-71.07978300000002'},
```

and got a good result.

if you want to generate them properly check out [How can we execute javascript in scrapy?](http://www.quora.com/Scrapy/How-can-we-execute-javascript-in-scrapy) or implement the same logic as a python method as part of your spider

Comment: Thanks, that was naive of me not to check parameters set in the request itself and assume they'd be the same ones as in the form.

Comment: @guy-gavriely trying something similar but unfortunately i am getting this error 

`from_response
     kwargs.setdefault('encoding', response.encoding)
 exceptions.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'encoding'
`

Can you please help me?

Comment: This error occurs because of this `request = FormRequest.from_response(url, formdata=frmdata, callback=self.parse_data)`

I think there is some issue with from_response